# How to activate the keyboard in qml (qt)

Tags: qt, qml

I have a Button object defined in Button.qml file, and another qml file Page.qml uses the Button object defined in Button.qml. How do I activate the keyboard input so that I can use keyboard to navigate the buttons in Page.qml. for example enter key, space key and etc.

I've tried using "focus: true", "Keys.onPressed:{}" and "onVisibleChanged: if (visible) sendBbkButton.forceActiveFocus()" both in Button.qml and Page.qml. But it does not activate the focus and keyboard for the two buttons in Page.qml.

Thanks!

### Page.qml:

```
Rectangle {
    id: bp

    // some code

     Button {
        id: aButton

        text: qsTr("Abort test1")
        tooltipText: qsTr("test1")
        onClicked: {
            // some coding
        }
        anchors { right: parent.left; bottom: parent.bottom; margins: 10 }
        height: contentHeight + 20
        width: contentWidth + 40
    }

    Button {
        id: bButton

        text: qsTr("Abort test2")
        tooltipText: qsTr("test2")
        onClicked: {
            // some coding
        }
        anchors { right: aButton.left; bottom: parent.bottom; margins: 10 }
        height: contentHeight + 20
        width: contentWidth + 40
    }

    // some code
}
```

---

### Button.qml:

```
BorderImage {
    id: button

    property alias text: label.text
    property alias contentWidth: label.contentWidth
    property alias contentHeight: label.contentHeight
    property alias buttonColor: shade.color
    property string tooltipText: ""

    signal clicked()

    source: Style.buttonBorderImage
    border { left: 10; top: 15; right: 10; bottom: 10 }
    Highlight { }
    width: Math.max( sourceSize.width, label.contentWidth * 1.2)

    Rectangle {
        id: shade
        anchors.fill: parent
        radius: 10
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: focusBorder
        color: "transparent"
        border.color: button.activeFocus ? Style.iRobotGreen : "transparent"
        anchors { fill: parent; margins: -1 }
        radius: 10
    }

    Layout.preferredWidth: Math.max( label.implicitWidth + button.border.left
                                     + button.border.right,
                                     button.implicitWidth )

    Text {
        id: label
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        font: Style.refFont1.font
    }

    MouseArea {
        id: mouse
        anchors.fill: parent
        enabled: true
        onClicked: button.clicked()
        hoverEnabled: button.tooltipText.length > 0
        onEntered: {
            if (button.tooltipText.length > 0)
                tooltip.show(mouseX + 16, mouseY + 16)
        }
        onExited: {
            tooltip.hide()
        }
    }

    ToolTip {
        id: tooltip
        enabled: true
        text: button.tooltipText
    }
}
```

---

Comment: where you put     focus: true
    Keys.onLeftPressed: console.log("move left").
Into the Item or in Item { Button { here }}

Comment: I put them in either inside Button of Page.qml or/and Button.qml, they do not work. Something like this - Button {
        id: bButton

        focus: true Keys.onPressed: ....} or inside the BorderImage {...} of Page.qml.